# ResourceDictionary shared variable

Tags: wpf, xaml, resourcedictionary

In my ResourceDictionary ***Resource_Color*** I have defined this row:

```
    <Color x:Key="MainColor">Black</Color>
```

Now, I want to use this **MainColor** in another resource file, for example ***Resource_DataGrid***.

```
        <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MainColor}" />
```

.
.
.
In this mode doesn't work. 
How can I write this declaration ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries`

**Window1.xaml**

```
<Window x:Class="Window1"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window1" Height="Auto" Width="Auto">
  <Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary2.xaml" />
  </Window.Resources>
  <Grid>
    <TextBox Text="TESTING" FontWeight="Bold" Margin="30" />
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Dictionary1.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Color x:Key="MainColor">Blue</Color>
  <SolidColorBrush x:Key="MainBrush" Color="{StaticResource MainColor}" />
</ResourceDictionary>
```

**Dictionary2.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <ResourceDictionary Source="Dictionary1.xaml" />
  </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

  <Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource MainBrush}" />
  </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Also, the Foreground property is usually a Brush, not a Color. My example shows it.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help ;-)